# Winstonjs - different formats for different levels?

Tags: node.js, logging, winston

I'm trying to dress up my log messages with winstonjs for easier debugging.  I am working within a *single transport* (namely `transports.Console`), and I want to use different formats for different levels.  For example, I have custom levels `info`, `warn`, `error`, and `header`.  For header, I use bold black:

```js
import Winston, { createLogger, format, info, transports } from 'winston';
 
const levels = {
    levels: {
        info: 0,
        header: 1,
        warn: 2,
        error: 3,
    },
    colors: {
        info: 'green',
        header: 'bold black',
        warn: 'yellowBG',
        error: 'red',
    },
};

const logger = createLogger({ 
    levels: levels.levels,
    transports: [
        new transports.Console({
            level: 'error',
            format: format.combine(
                format.colorize(),
                format.align(),
            ),
        })
    ]
});

Winston.addColors(levels.colors);
```

By default, the colors are applied to the level of the log, so we get this:

[image]

But what if I want the entire message to be bold for *just* the `header` level?

I know we can add options to `format.colorize()`, like `format.colorize({ all: true })`, which makes the whole message takes the color formatting.  However, this happens to all levels.  So it looks like this:

[image]

But I only want to apply the `all: true` option to the `header` level, and none of the other levels.

Is this possible?  I know its possible to create different transports with different formats, or different loggers, but can I use different formats for different levels within the same transport?  Or even customize the format of a single message one at a time (i.e. logger.log(message, someCustomFormatJustForThisMessage)` - Is anything like this possible?  (If this would be better asked as an issue on the winston repo, let me know)